# Array of Primitive Smaller than Primitive for ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, memory, serialization, memory-management

I have a function which takes in an object and turns it into an array of bytes:

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        try(ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)){
            o.writeObject(obj);
        }
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

When I use this function on primitive types, the output ends up being larger than a singleton array of that same primitive.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.format("byte    single: %d,    array: %d\n", 
            serialize((byte)   1).length, serialize(new byte[]{1}).length);

    System.out.format("short   single: %d,    array: %d\n", 
            serialize((short)  1).length, serialize(new short[]{1}).length);

    System.out.format("int     single: %d,    array: %d\n", 
            serialize((int)    1).length, serialize(new int[]{1}).length);

    System.out.format("float   single: %d,    array: %d\n", 
            serialize((float)  1).length, serialize(new float[]{1}).length);

    System.out.format("double  single: %d,    array: %d\n", 
            serialize((double) 1).length, serialize(new double[]{1}).length);

}
```

This produces:

> ```
> byte    single: 75,    array: 28
> short   single: 77,    array: 29
> int     single: 81,    array: 31
> float   single: 79,    array: 31
> double  single: 84,    array: 35
> ```

What is happening here? Why are the arrays smaller? Here is an [Ideone for the issue](http://ideone.com/GyGc3S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` is handling primitive arrays differently than other objects. You are not serializing primitives but objects as they get boxed before serializing so `int` becomes `Integer` etc.

For arrays, `ObjectOutputStream` just writes the following (I use `double` as an example)

```
1 byte // to mark it as array
22 bytes // for the class description
4  bytes // the length of the array
8 bytes // for the double (would be array.length * 8) is you have more elements
```

That makes 35 bytes as you observe in your experiment.

For other objects - like the boxed primitives - it uses more space as it has to store much more meta information. It has to store they type of the object and for each member it has to store the same information - so it kinda goes on recursively.

If you really want to understand what is going on in detail, I recommend reading the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java) of `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Java uses a different encoding for arrays which is more efficient.  If you serialize a `Byte`, it writes that you have an object (which you might reference later so it records an id) which has a class `java.lang.Byte` (which again has an id), which has a parent class `java.lang.Number` (also with an id), which has no fields, Byte has one field which is called "value" (which is a String with an id) and the value of the byte uses just one byte.

A byte[] has an internal name of `[B` which doesn't have parents of fields, so it is much shorter.